# jQuery detect image dimensions for multiple images in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jQuery:

```
jQuery(".storyImg").each(
function(){
    if(this.width() > this.height()){
        jQuery(this).addClass("landscape");
    } else if (this.width() < this.height()){
        jQuery(this).addClass("portrait");
    } else {

    }
}
);
```

It doesn't seem to be working. I can't even get it to fire an alert from inside the function. It's definitely included in the html file, and the class .storyImg is definitely correct.

Comment: Let me guess - either jQuery isn't loaded, or you need to move this to the bottom of your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `each` callback `this` refers to the dom element which does not have the `width` or `height` methods, you need to call those methods in the jQuery wrapper for the element

```
jQuery(".storyImg").each(function () {
    var $this = jQuery(this)
    if ($this.width() > $this.height()) {
        $this.addClass("landscape");
    } else if ($this.width() < $this.height()) {
        $this.addClass("portrait");
    } else {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `jQuery(this).width()` and `jQuery(this).height()` since `this` isn't a jQuery object. Your console should be littered with errors. You only need to call jQuery on `this` once.

You should also wait run this in `$(window).load()` since you want to wait for the images to load.

```
jQuery(".storyImg").each(function(){
  var $this = jQuery(this);
  if($this.width() > $this.height()){
    $this.addClass("landscape");
  } else if ($this.width() < $this.height()){
    $this.addClass("portrait");
  } else {

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

no js guru but you cant call `this.width()`. like you already have there use `jQuery(this).width()` maybe. better still add it to a var:

```
var $this = jQuery(this);
if($this.width() > $this.height()){
  // blah
}
```